# Program in c that takes an array and prints out and then finds its mean max and min. Not working properly

Tags: c

The program below is supposed to output

```
$ ./a.out  
Enter real numbers, up to 20, q to quit  
10 37 15 21 18 q  
You entered the following values:  
10.0 37.0 15.0 21.0 18.0  
The values have mean 20.2, max 37.0, and min 10.0  
$ ./a.out  
Enter real numbers, up to 20, q to quit  
q  
No valid numbers entered  
$ ./a.out  
Enter real numbers, up to 20, q to quit  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
You entered the following values:  
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0  
15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0  
The values have mean 10.5, max 20.0, and min 1.0
```

When i run my code i get

```
$ ./a.out  
Enter real numbers, up to 20, q to quit  
10 37 15 21 18 q  
You entered the following values:  
10.0 37.0 15.0 21.0   
The values have mean 20.8, max 37.0, and min 10.0
```

so the code cuts a number out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    float arr[20];
    int i,j;
    float mean, min,max,sum=0;

    printf("Enter real numbers, upto 20, q to quit : ");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        scanf("%f",&arr[i]);
            if(arr[i]==0){
                    i--;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i>0){
        printf("You entered the following values : \n");

        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            printf("%.1f ",arr[j]);//to print values upto 1 decimal
        }

        //finding mean = sum of numbers /no.of numbers
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
                sum = sum + arr[j];
        }

        mean = sum/i;//finding min and max :
        min = arr[0];
        max = arr[0];

        for(j=1;j<i;j++){
            if(arr[j]>max){
                max = arr[j];
            }

            if(arr[j]<min){
                min = arr[j];
            }
        }
        printf("\n The values have mean %.1f, max %.1f, and min %.1f",
               mean,max,min);
    }
    else
        printf("\nNo valid numbers entered");
}
```

Comment: Remove the `i--` in the first loop.  `i` is the index of the next element, i.e. it's the number of elements already entered.  You don't want to subtract 1 from it.

Comment: `i` is the last index you successfully `scanf` into so the loop should be `for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {` Also, a better way to check for success from `scanf` is to check its return value.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, `i` needs to be the number of elements, not the index of the last element.  It's not only clearer, but it's needed for the mean.  The loop is fine.  OP just needs to delete the decrement of `i` in the first loop.

Comment: As @klutt points out, it's not safe to assume anything about the contents of `arr[i]` if `scanf` doesn't parse a `float`.  Instead, you need to check the return value from `scanf`, which is the number of items successfully matched.  Exit the loop when it's zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` does not work the way you think. Use this:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    if(scanf("%f", &arr[i]) != 1)     
        break;
}
```

From documentation:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

So if it returns 0, it did not successfully read a float, which is to be expected when you enter a character instead.